# Node | TypeScript Error : ts-node-dev --rs (restart) option

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am using the --rs option (--rs - Allow to restart with "rs" line entered in stdio, disabled by default)
This is giving me error while running *npm run publish* :
[image]

The package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "nats-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "publish": "ts-node-dev --rs --notify false src/publisher.ts",
    "listen": "ts-node-dev --rs --notify false src/listener.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.0.23",
    "node-nats-streaming": "^0.3.2",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.51",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  }
}
```

Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: If you run `ts-node-dev --rs --notify false src/publisher.ts` directly, does that give you the same result?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the `--rs` flag to the `ts-node-dev` command:

```
ts-node-dev --rs src/publisher.ts
```